# RoR has many though extra fields access

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables: `employees`, `projects` and `teams`

```
Employee has_many :projects, :through => :teams
Project has_many :employees, :through => :teams
```

I added roles_id column to teams table.

```
Team belongs_to :role
```

Now I'm listing the projects, who's on the team and their role.

```
<% @project.employees.each do |employee| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= employee.employee_full_name %></td>
    <td><%= employee.team.role.rolecode %></td>
```

But, the role line is incorrect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are these all you relations? Looks like you haven't defined a relationship between `Team` and `Employee`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. Your associations are incomplete. See [this explanation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) that
   explains how to model a `has_many :through`;
2. An `employee has_many teams`, so you cannot say `employee.team`.

The solution for your first problem is that you have to define the following associations:

```
class Employee
  has_many :teams
  has_many :projects, :through => :teams
end

class Project
  has_many :teams
  has_many :employees, :through => :teams
end

class Team
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :project
end
```

As for you second problem: an employee can belong to more than one team, so you cannot do `employee.team`. You can only do `employee.teams`. The solution would be to change your iteration like this:

```
<% @project.teams.each do |team| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= team.employee.employee_full_name %></td>
    <td><%= team.role.rolecode %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

`roles_id => role_id` ?) or `belongs_to :role, :foreign_key => "roles_id"`

Comment: I have: team belongs_to role (using role_id foreign key).  The team table is the many to many table between employees and projects.  I was hoping I could use role as an additional column in team.